# Append a term to WooCommerce product existing product category terms

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, terms

I have a form which makes people decide about the sub-categories of their product and the form gets submitted on user post method

**Im trying to add the parent category to it as well**

Now I tested couple of way to adding the `$term` but each time it just get replaced not added

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'new_product_add', 10, 3);
function new_product_add($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
    if( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'pending' 
        && !empty($post->ID) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, 
            array( 'product') 
            )
        ) {
            $term = get_term_by('name', 'parent_category', 'product_cat');
            wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, $term->term_id, 'product_cat');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a missing boolean argument in [`wp_set_object_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) function like:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post->ID, $term->term_id, 'product_cat', true);
```

This time the term will be **appended** and not replaced.

You should check that the term doesn't exist yet on the product, before appending it like:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'new_product_add', 10, 3 );
function new_product_add( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if( 
        $old_status !== 'publish' 
        && $new_status === 'pending' 
        && ! empty($post->ID) 
        && $post->post_type === 'product'
    ) {
        $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
        $term_id  = get_term_by( 'name', 'parent_category', $taxonomy )->term_id;

        if( ! has_term( $term_id, $taxonomy ) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, $term_id, $taxonomy );
        }
    }
}
```